# swift method accept parameter if conform a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

i have a protocol named `WebServiceProtocol` and method like this :

```
class func executeRequest(delegate:__SOMETHING__,url:String,postParameters:[String:String],headerParameters:[String:String]){
   //Do something and call delegate
}
```

i want to have a conditional argument that check if input conform `WebServiceProtocol` Accept it.

i'm tying to write a global class function that work with every input , maybe a ViewController or NSObject class.

in java for classes we did like this :

```
<? extends SomeClass>
```

**Edit**
[image]
WebService.swift

```
import Foundation

protocol WebServiceProtocol {
    func onDataReceived(data:NSDictionary!)
    func onFailure()
}

class WebService:NSObject{

    class func executeRequest(delegate:WebServiceProtocol,url:String,postParameters:[String:String],headerParameters:[String:String]){
        if let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url){
            var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = arrayToHttpParams(postParameters).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
                    response, data, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let jsonString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                            if let dictionary = Helper.parseJson(jsonString as String) {
                                delegate.onDataReceived(dictionary)
                                println(dictionary)
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        println("failure !")
                        delegate.onDataReceived(nil)
                    }
                    else{
                        delegate.onFailure()
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    class func arrayToHttpParams(params:[String:String])->String{
        var mergedParams = [String]();
        for (key,value) in params {
            mergedParams.append(key+"="+value)
        }
        return "&".join(mergedParams);
    }
}
```

Authentication.swift

```
protocol AuthenticationLoginProtocol {
    func onSuccess(data:NSDictionary)
    func onFailure(data:NSDictionary)
}

class Authentication:NSObject,WebServiceProtocol{

   func attempLogin(delegate:ViewController,emial:String,password:String){

        var params = [String:String]();
        params["key1"]="value1"
        params["key2"]="value2"

        WebService.executeRequest(self, url: "", postParameters: params, headerParameters: params)

    }

    func onDataReceived(data: NSDictionary!) {

    }
    func onFailure() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want the method call to succeed even with an invalid parameter?

Comment: Oh.. you have a different problem, see my updated answer.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

You are trying to reference an instance in a **type** method. Instead of this,

```
WebService.executeRequest(self, url: "", postParameters: params, headerParameters: params)
```

write this:

```
WebService.executeRequest(Authentication.self, url: "", postParameters: params, headerParameters: params)
```

Then later in for example `Authentication`:

```
class Authentication: NSObject, WebServiceProtocol {

    // ...

    func someMethod() {
        WebService.executeRequest(self, url: "", postParameters: ["1": "2"], headerParameters: ["1": "2"])
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### Original answer

You could make a generic function with a type constraint for your protocol:

```
func myFunc<T: WebServiceProtocol>(input: T) {
  // input surely conforms to WebServiceProtocol
}
```

This way, T can be any type, as long as it conforms to the `WebServiceProtocol`.

For more details, see Type Constraints [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html).

Comment: this works for `Authentication()` as input but not working for `self` that is an `Authentication` sample .

Comment: same Error : `Cannot invoke 'executeRequest' with an argument list of type '(Authentication.Type, url: String, postParameters: [String : String], headerParameters: [String : String])'`

Comment: I've added a new method to my answer, it does not give any errors.

Comment: Thanks , not compile Error ! , let me test it more :D

Comment: Oh ! , attempLogin was class function and because of this self was not working :|  , thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "type method". ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you make the input take your protocol as the parameter type, the compiler will only compile if the parameter for that function implements that protocol, like above.

```
import UIKit

protocol WebServiceProtocol {

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    func takeProtocolAsInput(input: WebServiceProtocol) {

    }

    func otherFunc() {
        takeProtocolAsInput(A())

        // Compile-time error: B does not conform to WebServiceProtocol
        takeProtocolAsInput(B())
    }
}

class A: WebServiceProtocol {

}

class B {

}
```

Comment: this is my problem actually !

Comment: but i want to pass `self` as parameter in another class named `Authentication` that conform `WebServiceProtocol`

Comment: Can you post code for that to clarify what you are asking? It seems like if you are passing self, and self is an Authentication that conforms to WebServiceProtocol, then it should compile and work

Answer (score 1):

@József Vesza solution is good because Xcode will let you know if you're trying to pass in an object that doesn't conform to `WebServiceProtocol`. However, if you want to be able to pass anything (as specified in the question) to your function you could do the following:

```
func myFunc(obj: Any) {
    if let webService = obj as? WebServiceProtocol {
        // Do stuff with webService...
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it destroys the purpose of Swift being a strongly typed language.. :)

Comment: I agree, but the question asked for a 'global function that works with every input'.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that method generic

```
class func executeRequest<T: WebServiceProtocol>(delegate: T,url:String,postParameters:[String:String],headerParameters:[String:String]) {

}
```

There is an [article](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/03/26/protocols-and-generics-2/) about how this approach and @Will M.'s differ each other.